# Custom post type archive, more pages don't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site on which a lot of video's will be posted next week. The videos are posted with a custom post type, with just  'to', 'from' and yt video id. I wan to load a lot the videos on an archieve page, but not more than x per page. So x posts on page 1, x on page 2 and so on. Unfortunately, the page number doesn't show up, the 'p' container just stays empty. Here is my code:

```
      $args = array( 'post_type' => 'video'/*, 'posts_per_page' => 3 */);
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if (have_posts()) : 
    while ( $loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); 


                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <p><?php posts_nav_link('&#8734;','&laquo;&laquo; View newer posts','View older posts &raquo;&raquo;'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

I have emptied the part between the while, because in that part I only call to basic functions like the_permalink and the_content.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you have `if (have_posts()) : ` rather than `if ($loop->have_posts()) : `? The former is checking for the existence of posts in the DEFAULT loop. The latter checks for the existence of posts in your custom query.

Comment: No, that's a mistake, but that doesn't solve my problem

Comment: I didn't expect it to solve your problem, hence the comment. I was legitimately curious.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, using posts_nav_link in tandem with WP_Query doesn't work as expected, since posts_nav_link relies on the global $wp_query object, and doesn't recognize the custom WP_Query instance.

[This Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26960/posts-nav-link-not-displaying-anything) should provide you the details you need in order to get everything to work.

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$temp_wp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;

$paged = get_query_var('paged');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'video',
    'paged' => $paged ? $paged : 1
    /*, 'posts_per_page' => 3 */
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$wp_query = $loop;
if ($loop->have_posts()) : 
while ( $loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); 


<?php endwhile; ?>
<p><?php posts_nav_link('&#8734;','&laquo;&laquo; View newer posts','View older posts &raquo;&raquo;'); ?></p>
<?php
endif;
$wp_query = $temp_wp_query;
?>
```

Comment: Also, thank you for using WP_Query instead of query_posts. I swear, every time I see query_posts, I die a little bit inside.

Comment: I know do get the link to view different posts, but on page 2 and 3, I still see post 1-3, instead of 4-6 and 7-9...

Comment: @BastiaanZwanenburg Review the edit. When you're paginating your Posts, you need to pass a 'paged' argument to tell the Query how many posts to offset. This should get you started with what you need. If you have any other questions, feel free to open a new one.

Comment: I have the offset, but unfortunately I get thsi error: "Notice: Undefined variable: page"